# Cannot download Ubuntu using the Windows installer

Tags: wubi

I've tried three times to install Ubuntu using Windows installer.  The first time it hung up in Wubi.

Second time said it would take 6h 10 min.  Began running then *disappeared* after 30 minutes.

Third time it hung up with 5 min 10 sec displayed.

Any ideas? I'd like to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Ubuntu .iso, put it in the same directory (folder) as wubi.exe

See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F